# Building a data array in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I generate such data using a loop in JavaScript?

```
 data: [{
     y: 'bjjjjjjj mmnmmanf j',
     a: 98,
     b: 48

 }, {
     y: 'd',
     a: 50,
     b: 40
 }, {
     y: 'e',
     a: 75,
     b: 65
 }, {
     y: 'f',
     a: 50,
     b: 40
 }, {
     y: 'g',
     a: 75,
     b: 65
 }, {
     y: 'h',
     a: 100,
     b: 90
 }],
```

So far I've stored the data in the different arrays, but have no idea how can I 
generate the structure:

```
[{y:'d',a:98,b:48},{y:'d',a:50,b:40}, etc...]
```

Here are my arrays:

```
I_array = [98,50,75,50,75,100];
C_array = [48,40,46,40,65,90];
Name_array = ['b','d','e','f','g','h'];
```

Comment: Why are the values in separate arrays to begin with if you need them in the array-of-objects structure?

Comment: there are separate and you must make them one

Comment: I must, must I? So you aren't able to save yourself the conversion step by generating the right structure in the first place?

Comment: sorry to use "you" I must make them one

Comment: @ReginwaldtLed you can never guarantee the quality of the data you get by "making them one". It will be subject to many errors afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
I_array = [98, 50, 75, 50, 75, 100];
C_array = [48, 40, 46, 40, 65, 90];
Name_array = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

var s = "";

for (i = 0; i < I_array.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) s += ",";
    s += "{ \"y\":\"" + Name_array[i] + "\", \"a\":" + I_array[i] + ", \"b\": " + C_array[i] + " }";
}

var text = "{\"data\": [";
text += s;
text += "]}";

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ormsoev5/)

Comment: Why would you build up a string and then parse it when you can just build an array of objects directly?

Comment: Maybe he doesn't even need to parse it? In the question it wasn't specified.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
This is just an example. You can loop it according to your requirements.

```
var data = [];
for(var i = 0;i<4;i++)                   //your for loop starts here
{
    var obj = {};
    obj.y ='y';
    obj.a='a';
    obj.z='e';
    data.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Could also just do `data.push( {"y": y, "a":a, "z":z} );`

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes, but i think it will be more easy for anyone to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You could map it using javascript `array.prototype.map`:

```
var I_array = [98, 50, 75, 50, 75, 100];
var C_array = [48, 40, 46, 40, 65, 90];
var Name_array = ['b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

var newArray = Name_array.map(function (o, i) {
    return {
        y: o,
        a: I_array[i],
        b: C_array[i]
    };
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 1):

```js
var I_array = [98,50,75,50,75,100],
    C_array = [48,40,46,40,65,90],
    Name_array = ['b','d','e','f','g','h'],
    data = $.map( I_array, function(v, i) {
      return {        
        y: Name_array[i],
        a: v,
        b: C_array[i]
      };
    });

console.log( data );
$('body').text( JSON.stringify( data ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```